# Meteor Modify Boilerplate Response with Iron Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Using Iron Router I can add a route such as /index returns "INDEX CONTENT" from the server:

```
this.route('index', {
    path: '/',
    where: 'server',
    action: function () {
        this.response.end("INDEX CONTENT");
    }   
});
```

The default behaviour for a Meteor app is to return a boilerplate HTML file on the initial request to the server which contains the js/css etc required to run the web app.

What I would like to do, however, is place a string (ie "INDEX CONTENT" as above) within the boilerplate which would normally be returned by default if I hadn't added the route. To do this, I'd need to be able to modify a boilerplate response before it is sent to the client but after it is constructed by the standard meteor response mechanism.

Can anyone recommend a way to be able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [inject-initial](http://atmospherejs.com/package/inject-initial) meteorite package.

From the docs:

> `Inject.rawModHtml(id, func)`. At injection time, calls `func(html, res)` with the full page HTML which it expects to be returned, in full, after modification. `res` is the current http connection response request.

I think you would use it like this.

```
Inject.rawModHtml('breakEverything', function(html) {
    return "INDEX CONTENT";
});
```